# He and I / Him and me / He and me / Him and I

Tags: spoken-english, informal-language, case

> A: Where would you have the perfect date?
> B: In a place without people. Just him and me.

Is this written correctly?

Comment: No native speaker would ever say *There's no-one else here. Just **I*** (except "facetiously").  It's always ***Just me*** in such contexts, so obviously if the only person was someone *other* than the speaker, that would be ***Just him*** (certainly not ***Just he***). I can't see any justification for "mixed mode" (accusative+dative?) ***Just him and I / Just he and me***, but you might sometimes encounter ***Just he and I*** here. That's because *in principle*, B's second sentence might be "short for" ***He and I are** the only people*, as opposed to *The only people **are him and me***.

Answer (score 1):

The expression "Just him and me" doesn't contain a verb, so questions of whether something is subject of the verb or not are unanswerable.

The basic form in English is the object form.  In reduced expressions where there is no verb, we use the object form.

> Mum: Who wants some ice cream?
>
> Child: Me!

(but Child: "I want so ice cream", or "I do" if a verb is used)

Similarly in this reduced form you should use the object form.  A simple rule to apply is to use "I" or "He" when the pronoun *is* the subject, and "me" or *him* otherwise.

So:

> Just him and me.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment by  FumbleFingers says, the most correct ways to phrase this would be:

- > Just him and me. (object form)
- > Just he and I. (subject form)

However, the distinctions between "he" and "him" and between "I" and "me" are ones that native speakers are often careless about, particularly with complex subjects or objects. So one might encounter just about any combination of "I", "me", "him", and "he" used in such a construction written or particularly spoken by a native or fluent speaker. There is no intended difference of meaning in any of these variants, including the mixtures of case which are in fact incorrect.

**Add on in response to comment**:

Native speakers don't use an object pronoun at the start -- They say "I went.home", not "me went home". They are spmewhat more likely to use a subject pronoun as an indirect object, saying "He gave it to I" rather than "he gave it to me." When either subject or object is complex, consisting of two or more pronouns, or a noun and a pronoun, the distinction is not routinely carefully observed. It could be argued this means the distinction is not required, but a significant subset of native speakers do observe it, and will object if it is not observed. I will not enter here into the debate on what should be required when this construction is used.

Comment: Native speakers are not "careless about the distinction" when the pronoun occurs directly in the same constituent as the verb. It is only when other structures (such as coordination) intervene that they are unsure: and they are mostly unsure only because generations of pedagogues have insisted on what Joseph Emonds called ["Grammatically deviant prestige constructions"](http://fine.me.uk/Emonds/). There is no _a priori_ reason why the marginal feature of case should percolate into such structures.

Comment: @col Native speakers don't use an object pronoun at the start--They say "I went.home", not "me went home". They are a bit more likely to use a a subject pronoun as an indirect obj saying "He gave it to I"not "he gave it to me." When either subject or object are complex, beingof two or more pronouns, or a noun and a pronoun, the distinction is not routinely carefully observed. It could be argued this means the distinction is not required but a significant set of native speakers do observe it and will object if it is not observed. I will not enter here into the debate on what should be required.